# How to add support for a single missing character?

Tags: fonts, unicode, characters, missing

I keep getting this error:

```
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ❯ (U+276F) (U+276F) in font Roboto Mono Nerd Font Complet
```

---

Is there any way to add support for this entire font, or at least for this one character ?

> I use `xelatex` btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `newunicodechar`, but in a different way than David's, that is, using a substitute font.

```
\tracinglostchars=3
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmonofont{Roboto Mono}
\newfontfamily{\substitutett}{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\newunicodechar{❮}{\makebox[0.5em]{\substitutett❮}}
\newunicodechar{❯}{\makebox[0.5em]{\substitutett❯}}

\begin{document}

\texttt{❮abc❯}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `newunicodechar` package to make the characters active and fake however you wish, here I use a bold U+203A

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{❮}{\textbf{‹}}
\newunicodechar{❯}{\textbf{›}}

\begin{document}


‹this 1›

\textbf{‹}this 2\textbf{›}

❮this 3❯ 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you recommending to use a package of mine? Amazing! ;-)

Comment: @egreg because you are _so old_ by law of averages at least one of your packages must be useful!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very nice :-)))) the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much, both work, and are great solutions !